# Postfix fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: cannot open file: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, postfix, mail-server

I have recently installed postfix and while configuring the server have run into an issue. At one point I received the error from my syslog,

```
fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: cannot open file: Permission denied
```

I am logged in as `root`.
On another forum I had the recommendation to remove the file master.lock and to run an `apt-get update`, then restart.
I did these and log back in to find that my directory is empty.

```
ls -l /var/lib/postfix/
total 0
```

I have then tried to purge the program by doing `apt-get purge postfix` as root and reinstalling the program. 
No matter what I do, I cannot get the files back under `/var/lib/postfix/`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you permission problems or do you want to get files under `/var/lib/postfix`?

Comment: I want to get the files under the /var/lib/postfix. As far as I know, my permissions are OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `/var/lib/postfix/master.lock` is used to ensure that only **one** copy of Postfix's "`master`" process is active. If Postfix shuts down cleanly, all `/var/lib/postfix/*.lock` files will be deleted. If Postfix does not shut down cleanly, some `*.lock` files will be left over.

Comment: Ok that solves that issue. Now I have another. I cannot get postfix to start. Here is my main.cf:

Answer (score 0):

```
# fuser /var/lib/postfix/master.lock
/var/lib/postfix/master.lock: XXXX
# kill -9 XXXX
```

Start again

Comment: Unclear what you want the user to do in order to solve the issue.